# When deleting a comment, it remains in the chat

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, chat

1. I have wrote a comment.
2. My counterpart accepted move to the chat.
3. I have deleted the comment. It was deleted from comments OK. But when:
4. I moved to the chart, the comment was not deleted there. And the poor guy had  written already long but excessive answer to the canceled thought.

I think, the deleted comment should be deleted everywhere, or at least marked as deleted (strikethrough?) in the chat.

The time between 1 and 3 was about 2 minutes. Between 3 and 4 about 10-15 minutes. I do not know the time order of 2 and 3.

<sub>This is the chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7440/discussion-between-templatetypedef-and-gangnus

The deleted comment: "So, as I have already said, it depends on the way you have got that tree, not on the tree structure?"</sub>

Comment: It's really more of a feature request, given that this is effectively a *copy* operation...

Comment: It was deleted, but I see it. It looks like a bug.

Comment: But you deleted the comment *after* you suggest moving to chat and the other user accepted, i.e. after the chat messages were created, right? Again: *Moving to chat is like a copy operation*. If you delete one copy, the other isn't affected.

Comment: In fact, this behavior is *a feature*: It allows you (and moderators) to clean up lengthy comment threads on the site without affecting the discussion happening in chat.

Comment: 1. The way of realization can not be explanation for the way of use. Exceptions are acceptable only if the better realization is extremely expensive. So, copying is not an argument. Copying doesn't forbade to update the copy. 2. Explaining unnatural behaviour as a feature is not a good sign, too. The comment deleted was not put into chat, but into comments.

Answer (score 4):

No actions that are performed on a main site's comments will affect the migrated chat entries.

As Daniel Beck has indicated, comments on the main site are often deleted, allowing them to only remain in the chat transcript.