# Able to view any deleted or private chat message, with 20 rep

Tags: bug, status-norepro, chat, security, onebox

Normally, if you try to view a deleted message or a message from a private room, you will not be able to view its content. Deleted messages show as "(deleted)" in the room itself, are absent from the transcript (`https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/` + ID of message) and give a 404 if you [try to view history](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/8037908/history). Ordinary users cannot access private rooms directly or through the transcript, and history for those messages gives a 404.

But if you know the ID of the message you want to view (and this is guessable especially on low-traffic chat sites like meta.stackoverflow), you can view the contents, needing only 20 rep to be able to post a chat message. To do it, post a chat message

> `https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/` + ID of message

on any chat site, and the message will be oneboxed.

For example, from chat.meta.stackoverflow.com (where I am not a moderator), I can view the contents of a deleted message [by entering `https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8037950`](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1274599):

[image: bug]

Similarly, [I can view a message from the private Trashcan room](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1274530#1274530), and even [a deleted message from the private Trashcan room](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1274531#1274531):

[image: bug]

I can even view a message from the super-secret moderator-only Teachers' Lounge room [by writing `https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10`](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1274595#1274595).

[image: bug]

The message contents are visible from when logged-out, by browsing to the chat room. See http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38/conversation/exploit.

Related: [When deleting a comment, it remains in the chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121619/when-deleting-a-comment-it-remains-in-the-chat)

Comment: Uh... Am I missing something, or did you just post as bunch of messages that you, as a mod on chat.se, already had access to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a bold claim, but it's wrong.

You need more than just 20 rep on Meta for causing those messages to onebox. You also need **access to the message** – which you incidentally have, since you're a moderator on linguistics.se and thus on chat.stackexchange.com.